# Creating an associative array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

In this bash script I am attempting to combine two arrays into an associative array, so that in `combineArray` item 0 in the `newFSarray` is the key and item 0 in the 'oldFSarray' is the corresponding value, and so on for all 133 items.

Because I'm new at BASH I've pasted in the entire code exactly as I have it. It is quite possible that I'm making syntax errors. Currently I think something is not working in the `for loop` because in the output, no matter what `key` I select for the combineArray, I only every get the last value (see the current output below).

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -i arrayNum=$1-1

declare -a oldFSarray=(prollecture1 prollecture2 prollecture3 prollecture4 prollecture4b prollecture5 prollecture6 prollecture7 prollecture8 prollecture9 prollecture10 prollecture11 prollecture12 prollecture13 prollecture14 prollecture15 prollecture16 prollecture17 prollecture18 dthreelecture19 dthreeaonelecture20 dthreeaonelecture21 dthreeaonelecture22 dthreeaonelecture23 dthreeaonelecture24 dthreeatwolecture25 dthreeathreelecture26 dthreeafourlecture27 dthreeafivelecture28 dthreeafivelecture29 dthreeasixlecture30 dthreesixlecture30b dthreeasixlecture31 donelecture32 donelecture33 donelecture34 donelecture35 donelecture36 donelecture37 donelecture38 donelecture39 donelecture40 donelecture41 donelecture42 donelecture43 donelecture44 donelecture45 donelecture46 donelecture47 donelecture48 donelecture49 donelecture50 donelecture51 donelecture52 donelecture53 dTlecture54 dTlecture55 dTlecture56 dTlecture57 dTlecture58 dTlecture59 dTlecture60 dTlecture61 dTlecture62 dTlecture63 dTlecture64 dTlecture65 dTlecture66 dTlecture67 dTlecture68 dTlecture69 dTlecture70 dTlecture71 dTlecture72 dTlecture73 dTlecture74 dTlecture75 dTlecture76 dTlecture77 dClecture78 dClecture79 dClecture80 dClecture81 dClecture82 dClecture83 dClecture84 dClecture85 dClecture86 dClecture87 dClecture88 dClecture89 dClecture90 dClecture91 dClecture92 dLlecture93 dLlecture94 dLlecture95 dLlecture96 dLlecture97 dLlecture98 dLlecture99 dLlecture100 dLlecture101 dLlecture102 dLlecture103 dLlecture104 dLlecture105 dLlecture106 dLlecture107 dLlecture108 dLlecture109 dLlecture110 dLlecture111 dLlecture112 dLlecture113 dLlecture114 dLlecture115 dLlecture116 dLlecture117 dLlecture118 dLlecture119 dLlecture120 dLlecture121 dLlecture122 dLlecture123 dLlecture124 dLlecture125 dLlecture126 dLlecture127 dIlecture128 dIlecture129 dIlecture130 dIlecture131 dIlecture132 )

declare -a newFSarray=(Lectio_1 Lectio_2 Lectio_3 Lectio_4 Lectio_5 Lectio_6 Lectio_7 Lectio_8 Lectio_9 Lectio_10 Lectio_11 Lectio_12 Lectio_13 Lectio_14 Lectio_15 Lectio_16 Lectio_17 Lectio_18 Lectio_19 Lectio_20 Lectio_21 Lectio_22 Lectio_23 Lectio_24 Lectio_25 Lectio_26 Lectio_27 Lectio_28 Lectio_29 Lectio_30 Lectio_31 Lectio_32 Lectio_33 Lectio_34 Lectio_35 Lectio_36 Lectio_37 Lectio_38 Lectio_39 Lectio_40 Lectio_41 Lectio_42 Lectio_43 Lectio_44 Lectio_45 Lectio_46 Lectio_47 Lectio_48 Lectio_49 Lectio_50 Lectio_51 Lectio_52 Lectio_53 Lectio_54 Lectio_55 Lectio_56 Lectio_57 Lectio_58 Lectio_59 Lectio_60 Lectio_61 Lectio_62 Lectio_63 Lectio_64 Lectio_65 Lectio_66 Lectio_67 Lectio_68 Lectio_69 Lectio_70 Lectio_71 Lectio_72 Lectio_73 Lectio_74 Lectio_75 Lectio_76 Lectio_77 Lectio_78 Lectio_79 Lectio_80 Lectio_81 Lectio_82 Lectio_83 Lectio_84 Lectio_85 Lectio_86 Lectio_87 Lectio_88 Lectio_89 Lectio_90 Lectio_91 Lectio_92 Lectio_93 Lectio_94 Lectio_95 Lectio_96 Lectio_97 Lectio_98 Lectio_99 Lectio_100 Lectio_101 Lectio_102 Lectio_103 Lectio_104 Lectio_105 Lectio_106 Lectio_107 Lectio_108 Lectio_109 Lectio_110 Lectio_111 Lectio_112 Lectio_113 Lectio_114 Lectio_115 Lectio_116 Lectio_117 Lectio_118 Lectio_119 Lectio_120 Lectio_121 Lectio_122 Lectio_123 Lectio_124 Lectio_125 Lectio_126 Lectio_127 Lectio_128 Lectio_129 Lectio_130 Lectio_131 Lectio_132 Lectio_133 Lectio 134)

declare -a combineArray=();

for i in {0..133}
    do
        combineArray=("${combineArray[@]}" [$newFSarray[$i]]="${oldFSarray[$i]}");
    done

echo "old: "
echo ${oldFSarray[$arrayNum]}
new=${newFSarray[$arrayNum]}
echo "new: "
echo $new
echo ${combineArray[$new]}
```

This is the current output. Since I passed 2 as the initial parameter, I expected to get prollecture2 but instead got dIlecture132 (the last possible value)

```
$ ./plaoulFSArray.sh 2
old: 
prollecture2
new: 
Lectio_2
dIlecture132
```

Comment: (BTW is there a equivalent of php's print_r for bash so that I can see the result of combineArray?)

Comment: repeat after me: bash is not suitable for anything complex. bash is not suitable for anything complex. ... 5 minutes later, now go write your script in a proper scripting language, instead of bash. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop should look like this:

```
declare -A combineArray
for ((i=0; i<${#oldFSarray[@]}; i++))
    do
        combineArray+=(["${newFSarray[i]}"]="${oldFSarray[i]}")
    done
```

Even with associate arrays, `"${array[@]}"` only returns the values (`"${!array[@]}"` returns the keys). Use `+=(...)` to append to an array

Dump an array like this: `declare -p combineArray`

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm still getting the following error though line `19: ${newFSarray\[i\]}: bad substitution`

Comment: Weird - I didn't them - my machine seems to be adding them for me :(

Comment: what version of bash do you have?

Comment: I forgot to mention, you need `declare -A` for associative array.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.39(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin11.3.0)        - new error = `-bash: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
-bash: ${newFSarray\[i\]}: bad substitution`

Comment: I don't think `/bin/bash` is version 4.2, since Apple still ships version 3 (which does not support associative arrays) as the system shell. You may be using a newer installed version for your login shell, but your script is using the original.

Comment: That's annoyingly complicated -- can I update /bin/bash using macports

Comment: @glenn jackman I've accepted your answer since it seems like a great solution. It sounds like me new problem is upgrading bash (thanks @chepner). A new problem for a different discussion :)

Comment: I don't recommend replacing `/bin/bash`; `bash` doesn't retain complete backwards compatibility in newer versions (witness the various `compat*` options available). Rather, change the hashbang in your script to `!#/usr/local/bin/bash` or wherever you install the newer version of `bash`.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't more clearly documented in the man page: —— Use `+=(...)` to append to an array

Comment: It's here: [3.4 Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters), but it is buried in one of the lengthy paragraphs.